# How i can set values in a f.text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was trying to set value to a `f.text_field`
but I am unable to set the value

This is my code:

```
<%= f.label :example %><br>
<%= f.text_field :example, :value => 'example' %>
```

Comment: what value do you want to set exactly? A default value?

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

If you are passing an object and there is a field `example`, then you can get value of `example`.

If your object is empty and still you want to set value of `example`, then you can do it in controller action. Just use

```
object.example = "your value"
```

in your action that loads the view.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!